# Flip stargazer regression output

Tags: r, stargazer

I want to output a regression table with the covariates along the top, not down the side. This is rare, but not unheard of. See, for example, this table from [Baldwin & Taglioni (2006)](http://www.nber.org/papers/w12516):

[image]

It looks from [the docs, p.6](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stargazer/stargazer.pdf) as if this is only possible with summary tables, not with regression outputs.

With regression outputs, `flip=TRUE` does nothing:

```
> model <- lm('mpg ~ cyl + disp + drat + wt', data=mtcars)
> stargazer(model, type='text', flip=TRUE)
===============================================
                        Dependent variable:    
                    ---------------------------
                                NA             
-----------------------------------------------
cyl                          -1.786***         
                              (0.635)          
disp                           0.007           
 .                               .
 .                               .
 .                               .
```

I'd like to see something like this:

```
 cyl        disp      drat      wt
-1.786***   0.007    -0.010   -3.638***         
(0.635)    (0.012)   (1.338)  (1.102)
```

I'm not interesting in any summary statistics, so that needn't be a problem. I'm assuming it's a question of converting the `lm` object to a `data.frame` and then using `flip=TRUE` but not sure how to go about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could extract the coefficients and their standard errors and then feed that to `stargazer`:

```
model.summary = coef(summary(model))[, 1:2]
stargazer(model.summary, flip=TRUE)
```

Here's what the PDF output looks like:

[image]